# Keeping high scores on Unity web player

Tags: unity, databases, leaderboards

I want the player to be able to save his score when she makes it into top 10 of high scores. Upon success, player will be asked for a name to submit. This does not need to be unique per player. I just want a basic global score board available for everyone who plays the game via web player (from github.io page of the project).

When searched for how to keep high scores, I came across [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

> On Web players, PlayerPrefs are stored in binary files in the following locations:
>
> - **Mac OS X**: ~/Library/Preferences/Unity/WebPlayerPrefs
> - **Windows:** %APPDATA%\Unity\WebPlayerPrefs

As far as I understood, the results are kept in local machine and won't be same for everyone.
So it's good for keeping track of your own score, locally.

As a placeholder in the current version of the game, I keep the scores in a local .txt file in the project directory. Can I succeed with this approach and use the github.io server to maintain a global scoreboard or do I necessarily need a database to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a shared leaderboard for all players, then PlayerPrefs is not what you want. It's designed to save a file to the player's local computer, which only they can access. For a global leaderboard, you'll need to implement a server-side component for the game to communicate with.

[This page on the Unity wiki might be helpful to get you started.](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvKLmQ6VAtg

You will get the scripts / tutorial-package here:
http://mole.bplaced.net/?page_id=32

It is very easy with this help and completly free...